# Why JPA Hibernate Metamodel classes are used in Java app?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I a Java app that I work on, there are several metamodel classes e.g. "Company_". However, these are in target folder and I am wondering why do we use them because the other files e.g. "Company" will also be built and generated in the target folder. Then, what is the purposes using JPA Hibernate Metamodel classes in a Java app.

Any explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://thorben-janssen.com/static-metamodel/ for a discussion on this (no affiliation with the author, it was just the first good hit I got).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then, what is the purposes using JPA Hibernate Metamodel classes in a Java app.

**Why do we need metamodel classes you ask ?**

They are an internal detail which allows to achieve type safety for [criteria queries](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries). They are a means to an end. And this end is type safety for criteria queries. If this could be achieved in an easier way, without these extra classes it would be ideal to do it like this. Less classes -> less RAM used -> less classloading -> less startup time.

**Specifically, here's the motivation for this ...**

> When you write a criteria query or create a dynamic entity graph, you need to reference the entity classes and their attributes. The quickest and easiest way is to provide the required names as Strings. But this has several drawbacks, e.g. you have to remember or look-up all the names of the entity attributes when you write the query. But it will also cause even greater issues at later phases of the project if you have to refactor your entities and change the names of some attributes. In that case, you have to use the search function of your IDE and try to find all Strings that reference the changed attributes. This is a tedious and error-prone activity which will easily take up the most time of the refactoring.

You can lookup more [details](https://thorben-janssen.com/static-metamodel/) here.

If you want to go deep and understand why such an implementation was chosen to achieve this goal you can look at the original [Java Specification Request](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) and get all the details.

Does this resolve your question ? Let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for good explanations. Actually I had a look at [that](https://thorben-janssen.com/static-metamodel/) article, but I need some examples regarding to some issues. Could you pls clarify me about the following issues one by one?

Comment: **1.** I think when we use criteria queries, it is possible to call the same variable and change its value while it is used by another thread. For this reason, in order to perform these search in thread-safely, we should use metamodel classes. Is that right?

Comment: **2.** What if we use the corresponding classes of this metamodel classes? For example, in the **target** folder of the project, `Company` class is already generated. Then, why do not we use that `Company` class in the **target** folder and use `Company_` metamodel class?

Comment: Is there any other examples that we need to use metamodel classes? Some examples or scenarios pls?

Comment: OK. So, metamodel classes have one purpose to simplify criteria queries. They don't have any other purpose and use case. We don't use the Company class, because it has a different purpose and a different implementation. Take a look at the internals of the [metamodel](we should use metamodel classes.) class. Its just a collection of strings. It also has nothing to do with thread safety.

Comment: If this answer has helped you please feel free to accept and upvote so its easier for others to find it and reuse it.

Comment: You might also be interested in this https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries-metamodel#static-metamodel

Comment: I think I am confused with type safety and thread safety :) Then, there is nothing related to thread safety, and the purpose is simplifying criteria queries and type safety. Is that all true?

Comment: Yes. This is all true.

Comment: Thank you so much, marked as answer and voted up ;)