# How JPA Metamodel Classes works?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to understand how meta classes works. Here is one example

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "students")
    public class Student {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
    
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
    
    }


@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Student.class)
public abstract class Student_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Student, String> firstName;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Student, Integer> id;

    public static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    public static final String ID = "id";

}
```

want to know in generated meta class `Student_` for `Student`, what's a purpose of having 2 attributes for single ?

For example, lets say for firstName, there are two forms in meta class

```
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Student, String> firstName;
public static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
```

In what sense its required in generated class and how its being used internally ? What's a diff between `firstName` and `FIRST_NAME` ? which one to use when ?

Secondly, Just writing `@Column(name = "first_name")` wont work and not creating meta class like above ? because even am using `firstName` attribute at so many places, wouldn't be a good idea to just change in `col` name in annotation in case if change of col name happens in future ? Will it fulfill the essence of what generated `meta classes` are doing ?

Comment: So, do you know how these metamodel classes are used? I used them once in CriteriaQuery. `FIRST_NAME` and so are used to refer to fields/columns in CriteriaQuery. And the meta model classes are generated by adding the dependency of hibernate model-gen in the pom. I guess these classes are meant to be used, and not studied(you can still investigate, but they are impl. details, I mean)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why JPA Hibernate Metamodel classes are used in Java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912260/why-jpa-hibernate-metamodel-classes-are-used-in-java-app)